# Как спарсить html, если часть его скрыта?

Tags: html, python, парсер, bs4

Решил спарсить сайт аптеки ( http://lekvapteke.ru/ )
Долго не мог понять почему не получается найти основные элементы страницы, потом в браузере докапался до раздела Response в Network, где был точно такой же html как и при парсинге (а пишу я кстати на Python)
В общем вопрос в том, как получить доступ к полному коду страницы?
[image: html в Response]
[image: Основной html]
[image: Навсякий скрин взятия html, но это и так понятно]

Comment: Добавьте ваш код текстом, а не фотографией

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ты ищешь, например, Регидрон, то сначала они генерируют динамический УРЛ

```
http://lekvapteke.ru/medicaments/regidron
```

По этому урлу генерируют страницу, внутри которой будет код, который подгрузит результаты поиска

```
    medicamentParams = params;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajaxgetpharmacieswithmedicamentshortname/regidron/' + params + '?shown_elements=' + shown_elements,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            ShowBlockerWindow();
        },
        complete: function () {
            HideBlockerWindow();
        },
```

Которые будут в JSON формате

[image: список аптек]

Тебе уже посоветовали Selenium, он как раз позволит эмулировать юзера и броузер. Альтернативным советом будет перестать тырить данные и обратиться к авторам сайта, возможно они предоставят тебе платное (а если повезёт, то и бесплатное) API.

---

Судя по всему, даже Селениум не особо нужен. Достаточно найти их правила конвертации русских символов в латинские и можно просто делать JSON запросы.

Например, Ботокс

http://lekvapteke.ru/ajaxgetpharmacieswithmedicamentshortname/botoks/0?shown_elements=0

Answer (score 1):

В python существует плагин selenium, изначально он предназначен для автоматического тестирования путем автоматизации браузера. По факту он открывает Ваш браузер и делает все тоже самое что и вы за Вас...

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

https://habr.com/ru/post/248559/

https://habr.com/ru/post/250921/

Answer (score 0):

Корректнее в данном случае сказать не "полный код" страницы, а HTML, который строится динамически в браузере с помощью JavaScript после загрузки первоначального HTML кода с сервера (то что вы видите в своем парсере). Решить эту задачу можно программно запуская браузер, например Headless Chrome. Другим вариантом может быть исследование запросов в панели Dev Tools, которые страница делает после загрузки и парсить непосредственно их.

Comment: Большое спасибо, понял в каком направлении двигаться. Думал тут проблема кроется в защите от Парсинга, а не в построении сайта